# Get ag-grid instance by container div Id

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I know that in order to generate a new ag-Grid we can do the following:

```
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
```

Where gridDiv is the "container div" of the ag-grid and gridOptions , the options of the grid.

Is it possible to fetch the grid instance given that I have its "container div" Id?
I basically want to access its gridOptions / gridOptions.api

Comment: If your gridOptions is still available to you, after grid creation that object will contain access to your the grid api and column api

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this?

Comment: Save it when creating the `Grid`? Do you have an access to the code, or you're trying to get data from some 3rd party which uses `apGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you have access to the code.

You can get access to the API if you have control of the `gridOptions`. Once the grid is intialized, which means after this line is executed

```js
new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
```

It passes [`gridApi`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/) and [`columnApi`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/) to your `gridOptions`. You can begin to manipulate the table whatever you want. Here is a small example

```js
// at this point you don't have accesss to the API yet
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData,
};

var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

// initialize ag-grid
new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);

// grid APIs are ready, we can print current column state for example
console.log(gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState());

setTimeout(() => {
  var sort = [
    { colId: 'price', sort: 'desc' },
  ];
  gridOptions.api.setSortModel(sort);
}, 2000)
```

See the live demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-javascript-hello-world-o1hm86?embed=1&file=index.js)

### Reference

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid

Comment: This dosn't really answer the question. In case gridOptions are unavailable and you would like to retrieve the grid instance from the element afterwards - this is what the question needs an answer for.

Comment: Can you explain more about your situation? why is the `gridOptions` inaccessible in your case?

Comment: If you are writting an e2e test it wpuld be nice, to be able to interact with the grid e.g. for scrolling. 
I once tried to implement some hotkeys for widget selection and tried to tell ag-grid to get focus. Did not work w/o the API; I had to create a custom event and to listen on this event in my widget to pass the call to ag-grid.